# Why will only one partition on my external drive show up in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, external-hard-drive

I running an Ubuntu 10.10 server which I interact with through the command line. It has an external hard drive attached to it, which has two partitions. One of the partitions, which has about 250MB on it, mounts, but not the other, which has the other 249.75GB of storage in it.

I know that the drive has two partitions because I plugged it into my Mac, which shows one partition named disk1s1 and one named disk1s5. Neither will mount on my Mac, because of their disk format. In Ubuntu, I can't see any sign that the second partition exists.

I realize that this is a basic question, but I am relatively new to Linux, and much of the advice available is for people with a graphic interface. How can I see/gain access to the second partition on my disk?

Thank you,
Rebecca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your problem here is what you need to find out/know. Were the partitions created with Windows, MAC or Linux or was the drive bought already formatted? What is the total size of the disk?

sudo fdisk -l

The above command will list your drives and give you information about the partitions.

I had a similar problem with mounting an exFAT disk, To resolve the problem I installed FUSE exFAT.

The two links below should be of help regarding ubuntu and file systems.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions

The next link is for exFAT

https://launchpad.net/~relan/+archive/exfat